# Auto-scrape realm metrics from Keycloak with Prometheus-Operator

Tags: keycloak, monitoring, metrics, prometheus-operator

I installed Keycloak using the `bitnami/keycloak` Helm chart (https://bitnami.com/stack/keycloak/helm).

As I'm also using Prometheus-Operator for monitoring I enabled the metrics endpoint and the service monitor:

```yaml
keycloak:
  ...
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: true
      namespace: monitoring
      additionalLabels:
        release: my-prom-operator-release
```

As I'm way more interested in actual realm metrics I installed the `keycloak-metrics-spi` provider (https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi) by setting up an init container that downloads it to a shared volume.

```yaml
keycloak:
  ...
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: providers
      mountPath: /opt/bitnami/keycloak/providers

  extraVolumes:
    - name: providers
      emptyDir: {}
  ...
  initContainers:
    - name: metrics-spi-provider
      image: SOME_IMAGE_WITH_WGET_INSTALLED
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command:
        - sh
      args:
        - -c
        - |
          KEYCLOAK_METRICS_SPI_VERSION=2.5.2
          wget --no-check-certificate -O /providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-${KEYCLOAK_METRICS_SPI_VERSION}.jar \
            https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/${KEYCLOAK_METRICS_SPI_VERSION}/keycloak-metrics-spi-${KEYCLOAK_METRICS_SPI_VERSION}.jar
          chmod +x /providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-${KEYCLOAK_METRICS_SPI_VERSION}.jar
          touch /providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-${KEYCLOAK_METRICS_SPI_VERSION}.jar.dodeploy
      volumeMounts:
        - name: providers
          mountPath: /providers
```

The provider enables metrics endpoints on the regular *public-facing* `http` port instead of the `http-management` port, which is not great for me. But I can block external access to them in my reverse proxy.

What I'm missing is some kind of auto-scraping of those endpoints. Right now I created an additional template, that creates a new service monitor for each element of a predefined list in my chart:

`values.yaml`

```yaml
keycloak:
  ...
  metrics:
    extraServiceMonitors:
      - realmName: master
      - realmName: my-realm
```

`servicemonitor-metrics-spi.yaml`

```yaml
{{- range $serviceMonitor := .Values.keycloak.metrics.extraServiceMonitors }}
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Release.Name }}-spi-{{ $serviceMonitor.realmName }}
...
spec:
  endpoints:
    - port: http
      path: /auth/realms/{{ $serviceMonitor.realmName }}/metrics
...
{{- end }}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? So that Prometheus can auto-detect all my realms and scrape their endpoints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO you don't need to scrape every realm metrics endpoint - see README: `The endpoint lives under <url>/auth/realms/<realm>/metrics. It will return data for all realms, no matter which realm you use in the URL (you can just default to /auth/realms/master/metrics).` So main `master` realm is enough to monitor all realms.

Comment: Interesting. I looked at the README multiple times. Should read the sentences more carefully. Always understood it as "this is the endpoint your get the data from (per realm)". Just checked it and yes, the _master_ endpoint also returns data from my other realms. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by @jan-garaj there is no need to query all the endpoints. All return the accumulated data of all realms. So it is enough to just scrape the endpoint of one realm (e.g. the master realm).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It might help someone, the bitnami image so the helm chart already include the metrics-spi-provider. So do not need any further installation action but the metrics must be enabled in values.

Comment: Could you link some documentation for this? Since when is this included? Keycloak 14 does not have it yet. Threre is a metrics endpoint, but that one does not provide any realm metrics.

Comment: I also can find no mention of it in the chart. It still says _If additional containers are needed in the same pod (such as additional metrics or logging exporters), they can be defined using the sidecars config parameter._

Comment: There is no documentation afaik. You have to enable metrics and create a servicemonitor. Then it should work. I am running without extra container or as you did above. I am using the latest version of chart and image.

Comment: Ok, interesting. And you're getting realm metrics? Not only Wildfly metrics? Which Keycloak version are you using? Will try this with the next upgrade.

Comment: I am getting realm metrics and using the provided dashboard [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10441).  keycloak  16.1.0

Comment: Ok, great! Will give it a try once I update :)

Comment: @MaxN. how did you enable metrics listener event? I mean is there a way to automate it?

Comment: There might be. But I just enabled in manually on all my realms.