# Keycloak http-management returns Connection refused

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak, prometheus, metrics

I have Keycloak 14 running and would like to scrape metrics data from it.

So I configured Prometheus to scrape `http://KEYCLOAK_HOST:9990/metrics`. Unfortunately this gives me a "Connection refused".

When I try to connect from another host manually I get the same:

```
user@host:/$ curl -vvv 10.244.3.154:9990/metrics
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x5566ecabbfb0)
*   Trying 10.244.3.154...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5566ecabbfb0)
* connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990: Connection refused
user@host:/$
```

In fact I get this error on all paths on the management port. Even on those, that do not exist:

```
user@host:/$ curl -vvv 10.244.3.154:9990/some_endpoint
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55eea4059fb0)
*   Trying 10.244.3.154...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55eea4059fb0)
* connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990: Connection refused
user@host:/$
```

From within the Keycloak host it works fine:

```
bash-4.4$ curl -vvv localhost:9990/metrics
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9990 (#0)
> GET /metrics HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9990
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
...
bash-4.4$
```

It only works on `localhost` though:

```
bash-4.4$ hostname -I
10.244.3.154
bash-4.4$ curl -vvv 10.244.3.154:9990/metrics
*   Trying 10.244.3.154...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.3.154 port 9990: Connection refused
bash-4.4$
```

So I assume Keycloak is not providing the management endpoints "to the outside world". But how can I enable it?

I'm using the `codecentric` Helm chart for deployment (https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak). I'm running Keycloak 14.0.0 right now, but had the same issue with 15.x (cannot update right now due to a bug).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the values that you used for the helm install?

Comment: I did not really configure anything there. I enabled `ingress` and `postgres`, configured the `serviceMonitor` and `extraServiceMonitor` and added a `prometheusRule` (with rules from the `keycloak-operator` repo). The only thing I could think of, that could be interesting is an extra init container I add, that install `metrics-spi-provider`. You can see the setup here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751203/auto-scrape-realm-metrics-from-keycloak-with-prometheus-operator (I was using another chart back then, but the script did not change).

Comment: Ok nvm. Found an issue in the Charts repo, that points to the documentation.
* https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/436
* https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#prometheus-metrics-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found in the documentation of the Helm chart, that I had to enable it by setting the env variable `KEYCLOAK_STATISTICS` to `all`.

https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#prometheus-metrics-support